# Various quirks on revamped site with mobile Chrome browser

Tags: bug

Since the header bar on Stack Overflow was revamped several weeks ago, I have noticed a few quirks when using SO on my mobile Chrome browser on Android.  The most annoying is that giving the focus to an input box no longer causes the screen to center around that input.  To be more precise, when I used to give the focus to an input element, my mobile browser would center around it, making it easy for me to see what I type in.  This is no longer the case, and it requires an extra step to center the screen.  While this may sound trivial, when you're trying to compete with guys like Gordon Linoff on your subway ride to work, such usability details can be the difference between a green checkmark and a lump of coal.

I have also noticed some UI rendering problems lately.  Just now, I observed this on my Android mobile Chrome browser:

[image]

As you can see, the comments on the bottom have gone haywire, and are sprawling across the entire page.  This screenshot was in landscape, by the way, but going back to portrait didn't complete fix the problem either.

Is the revamped site still in a quiet beta mode, or is it considered "finished?"

Comment: I don't know what's going on there, but I cannot reproduce that on my android phone using chrome.

Comment: Please add version numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure that Chrome on Android is a supported browser for the desktop site (assuming that's what you're viewing).

Comment: Android Chrome version `56.0.2924.87`